# Traversing the dom, finding the closest previous checkbox

Tags: jquery, traversal

I am trying to traverse the dom in the code below and just having a block mentally. I would like to enable the checkbox in the previous .form-input-wrapper.

```
<div>
  <div class="form-input-wrapper inline-radio-buttons">
    <span class="button-label">Setup - Ready</span>
    <span>
      <input id="status_0" name="status[0]" type="hidden" value="setup_ready">           
      <input checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="status_0" name="status[0]" type="checkbox" value="setup_ready">
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-input-wrapper inline-radio-buttons">
    <span class="button-label">Setup - Required</span>
    <span>
      <input id="status_1" name="status[1]" type="hidden" value="setup_required">
      <input checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="status_1" name="status[1]" type="checkbox" value="setup_required">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a number of things. This is what I currently doing:

(NOTE: this is for context) Basically I have a column of checkboxes. If they are checked they are disabled, except for the last one. if you uncheck the last one, I want to enable the checkbox above.

```
$(@checkboxes).live 'click', ->
  if $(this).is(':checked')
    return
  else
    console.log "$(this).parents() ", $(this).parent().prev().has(':checkbox').first().find(':checkbox')
    console.log $(this)
    $(this).parent().prev().has(':checkbox').first().find(':checkbox').disabled = false
    return
```

if I log:

```
$(this).parent().prev().has(':checkbox').first().find(':checkbox')
```

this log will just print out the element I clicked on.

Comment: Are you sure what you want to do is enable/disable, not check/uncheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go up 2 levels, but I consider it better to use `.closest()` to specify a selector, rather than hard-coding the number of levels in the code.

For the first, use:

```
$(this).closest(".inline-radio-buttons").siblings().first().find(":checkbox").prop("disabled", false);
```

For the previous, use:

```
$(this).closest(".inline-radio-buttons").prev().find(":checkbox").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: hmm, close. this enables the first checkbox. I tried to replace first() with prev() and that just enabled all of the checkboxes.

Comment: Don't use `siblings()` if you just want the previous. I've updated the answer.

Comment: ha!, I just figured that out and was going to edit it :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I changed the following to bring it to work:

- Use `closest` instead of `parent` as it is more stable because you can nest as much as you want then.
- Do not use `first` at that point, because `prev` will return `1` or `0` elements. The `first` changes nothing.
- Added an element to the HTML, that does not have `disabled="disabled"`
- Changed `.disabled = false` to `.removeAttr('disabled')` (I think `.disabled = false` would not work)

```js
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
  $(':checkbox').live('click', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      return;
    $(this).closest(".form-input-wrapper").prev().has(':checkbox').find(':checkbox').removeAttr('disabled');
    return;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="form-input-wrapper inline-radio-buttons">
    <span class="button-label">Setup - Ready</span>
    <span>
      <input id="status_0" name="status[0]" type="hidden" value="setup_ready">           
      <input checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="status_0" name="status[0]" type="checkbox" value="setup_ready">
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-input-wrapper inline-radio-buttons">
    <span class="button-label">Setup - Required</span>
    <span>
      <input id="status_1" name="status[1]" type="hidden" value="setup_required">
      <input checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="status_1" name="status[1]" type="checkbox" value="setup_required">
    </span>
  </div>
  <!-- Element inserted by me to be able to test one without disabled="disabled" -->
  <div class="form-input-wrapper inline-radio-buttons">
    <span class="button-label">Setup - 3</span>
    <span>
      <input id="status_2" name="status[2]" type="hidden" value="setup_required">
      <input checked="checked" id="status_2" name="status[2]" type="checkbox" value="setup_required">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try `$(this).parentsuntil('elem')`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.removeAttr('checked')` if click.

Sample :

```
$('input').bind('click', function () {  
$('.inline-radio-buttons').last().find('input').removeAttr('disabled').removeAttr('checked');
});
```